# Synonym Tag: APP and appexchange

Tags: feature-request, tags

Can we add a synonym to APP-exchange?

I am not sure which should be the main, but the 2 are the same

(even that no one has yet to tag: appexchange)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think they are synonyms, though.  Inside Salesforce, App has a specific meaning of a grouping of tabs for a user, while the AppExchange is a place to go for maintained managed packages.

Comment: APP as I see it refers to the General Application - the entire scope of my setup (app) Interesting to see if this will cause duplicates or wrong tagginsg